# "unfortunately app stooped working" after adding background image

Tags: android, android-layout

**Unfortunately app stopped working **

After building an APK with a background image.

I am a newbie to android, I thought of developing a beginner app likely(note app in phones). It was far good till applying a background image in the .xml file. after the update, the APK file failed to run on mobile. Can anyone suggest where I went wrong?

[image: Layout Image of setting background]

Comment: What is the error u r getting? Is that image size too big? Post the error log

Comment: please add your XML code.

Comment: Add the crash log

Comment: Fatal exception

Comment: `failed to build` and `unfortunately app stopped working`  are 2 opposite things. Please decide whether it failed to build, or successfully built, but crashing.

Comment: Build successfull. but getting *unfortunately app stopped working*

Comment: Please share your crash log of logcat

Comment: then edit your question to correspond to your real problem. The title says that you can't build it.

Comment: and once you say word `crash` you have to provide the crash stacktrace immediately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I suspect Binary XML error but like everybody said provide error log

Answer (score 0):

Please check dimensions of image it should be not greater than 1280x1920 otherwise it will give outofmemory error
you can also add large heap true in manifest file